# Setting up StrongLoop with my node applications

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I'm currently testing platforms that provide a monitoring service for nodejs application. So I found (for now) StrongLoop and AppDynamics (recently acquire nodetime).

Actually I'm testing StrongLoop service. I have followed all the steps describe in the documentation but I can't see any data on the dashboard, only the StrongLoop Demo App. Here is all the steps :

- npm install -g strongloop
- npm install --save strong-agent
- $ slc strongops (command that create strongloop.json file)
- add "require('strong-agent').profile();" line on first line of each applications (2)
- restart my applications (using PM2 to manage my applications - cluster mode, AWS EC2, Ubuntu)

Any idea ?

Tank you.

Comment: My answer with links got deleted by another SO user so I'm listing the steps here. 

First uninstall using this      

$ npm uninstall -g strong-cli
$ npm uninstall -g loopback-sdk-angular-cli

and then install

npm install -g strongloop

You can now run slc strongops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer with links got deleted by another SO user so I'm listing the steps here.

First uninstall using this

$ npm uninstall -g strong-cli
$ npm uninstall -g loopback-sdk-angular-cli

and then install

npm install -g strongloop

You can now run slc strongops

and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Linux init.d Daemon script which you can use to run your app with slc as service:
https://gist.github.com/gurdotan/23311a236fc65dc212da

Might be useful to some of you.